# I can't get rails server to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ROR and I'm building a new app. I wanted to restart the server, but all of a sudden this is the message I get:

> user@ubuntu:~$ cd blogger
>
> user@ubuntu:~/blogger$ rails s
>
> => Booting WEBrick
>
> => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on 
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>
> => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using <127.0.0.1 (--binding option)>
>
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting
>
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport4.1.1/lib/active_support/
>
> dependencies.rb:241:in `load': /home/user/blogger/config/routes.rb:60:
>   syntax error,
>
> unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)   from
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-
>
> 4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'   from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-

Comment: can you post your routes.rb?  That's where the problem is as it says in the log: /home/user/blogger/config/routes.rb

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  resources :posts
    resources :comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it says you have a syntax error in your config/routes.rb.
Check the brackets and "do end" blocks in this file.